# Spark - How to create a RDD from Kinesis input without using streaming libraries

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, amazon-kinesis

I'm wondering how to create an RDD reading data from **Kinesis** with a specific offset, with a **non-streaming Spark job**.
For Kafka I know this is possible with KafkaUtils.createRDD.
But I don't find the same library for Kinesis. Any suggestion or workaround?

Thanks!